# Как при парсинге страницы найти тег с определенным классом?

Tags: requests, beautiful-soup, bs4, steam

При парсинге страницы я не могу по какой-то причине найти тег с определенным классом. Без понятия, почему так происходит.

Вот пример кода:

```
def function1_request(url):
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 YaBrowser/21.2.3.100 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
    ret_url = requests.get(url, HEADERS)
    return ret_url


def sbor_dannyh(dan1_url):
    dan_url = function1_request(dan1_url)
    soap1 = BS(dan_url.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soap1)
    price_thing = soap1.find('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee').text.strip()
    #print(price_thing)
    #print(price_thing.split(' ')[0])
    print(price_thing[:-5])
    standart_price = soap1.find('span', {'id': 'market_commodity_buyrequests'})
    print(standart_price)

print(sbor_dannyh('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20CZ75-Auto%20%7C%20Imprint%20%28Field-Tested%29?filter=%22Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%2C%20Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%22'))
```

Помогите понять, в чем проблема?

Comment: третий None от того, что функция sbor_dannyh ничего не возвращает, а вы это принтите... а что должно быть вторым?

Comment: Проблема вот в этой строке: standart_price = soap1.find('span', {'id': 'market_commodity_buyrequests'})
    print(standart_price)

Comment: я знаю )) что за standart_price? где он на той странице?

Comment: Если в краток, то на странице, которая указана в коде, есть цена (начальная цена) и вот ее я не могу спарсить. Находиться рядом с зелёной кнопкой заказать.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> на странице, которая указана в коде, есть цена (начальная цена) и вот
> ее я не могу спарсить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20CZ75-Auto%20%7C%20Imprint%20%28Field-Tested%29?filter=%22Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%2C%20Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%22'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

# .find_all() на случай, если вернется не одна позиция
market_listing_rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='market_recent_listing_row')

for row in market_listing_rows:
    name = row.find('span', class_='market_listing_item_name').text

    price_with_fee = row.find('span', class_='market_listing_price_with_fee').text.strip()
    price_with_publisher_fee_only = row.find('span', class_='market_listing_price_with_publisher_fee_only').text.strip()
    price_without_fee = row.find('span', class_='market_listing_price_without_fee').text.strip()

    print(name)
    print(price_with_fee)
    print(price_with_publisher_fee_only)
    print(price_without_fee)
```

выведет:

```
StatTrak™ CZ75-Auto | Imprint (Field-Tested)
87,74 pуб.
83,93 pуб.
76,30 pуб.
```

Comment: Это не решает никак проблему. Мне нужно спрасить "НАЧАЛЬНАЯ ЦЕНА" и ее значение. А это значение постоянное подгружается с фалов xhr. И мне нужно как то их получить

Comment: @VeySheng рядом с зеленой кнопкой 87,74 pуб., про которые вы писАли, не то, разве? а где то, что нужно, на скриншоте?

Comment: Да уже не надо, я только что нашел другое решение, оно труднее, но дает больше данных. Теперь новая проблема))

Answer (score 0):

То что вам надо находится вот тут https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=5&item_nameid=165027660&two_factor=0
вытаскиваете со страницы переменную item_nameid=165027660

потом уже запрос на https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram, где выводится вся инфа по ордерам